# Is Data Warehousing the Right Solution

Tags: database, caching, data-warehouse, information-retrieval, data-retrieval

I have a vendor system that I can query to get reports or raw data. The data returned are based on internal calculations, I can get also get data based on dates.

I have some reports that tend to take a very long time to return results. I think the vendor's data retrieval (calculations and operation) is the main problem.

I'm thinking of using a data warehouse as a sort of cache, so the reports that are queried often can be retrieved from the warehouse. This will mean daily or hourly retrieval of the necessary data and storing it in the warehouse.

Is this a good solution?
Is there a existing tool that does something like this?

Comment: It could be a good solution, might also be worth analysing the query plans and making sure the vendor's calculations are indeed the problem. Have you done any query analysis?

Comment: @YannickLiekens Thanks for the feedback. No, I haven't designed the tables yet, just wanted to know if it's a solution that can work.